# networkx python, directed/undirected graph, inconsistent nodes and edges?

Tags: python, networkx

I have creating a graph on which I run pagerank. I have tested both directed and undirected graphs but I struggle to understand what I see.

I have a block of code that look like below:

```
G= nx.DiGraph() #option 1
#G= nx.Graph() #option 2
[inside a for loop]
   G.add_edge(node, another_node)
print("Graph size {} {}".format(len(G.nodes()), len(G.edges())))

[then code to run pagerank...]
```

which as you can see, I try both directed graph (DiGraph) and undirected graph (Graph). For both, I go through the same loop, that call 'add_edge' same number of times, on the same set of (node, another_node) pairs.

Then I print the number of nodes and edges on the resulting graph. However, this is the line that baffles me. Because for DiGraph and Graph, I see different output:

When option 1 is used, there are 10107 nodes and 1350222 edges.
When option 2 is used, there are 10107 nodes and 1268064 edges.

I do know understand the consistency. is this normal or what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edges in an undirected graph have no direction. Edges from A to B and from B to A are considered duplicates. `add_edge()` silently ignores duplicates. That is why your undirected graph would have one edge (A,B) or (B,A) where the directed graph would have two edges, (A,B) and (B,A).